# Find the value of $(g-Pg)(x);x\in [0,1]$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a closed subspace of $L^2[0,1]$ and let $f,g\in L^2[0,1]$ be given by $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$.If $V^\perp=\operatorname{Span }f$ and $Pg$ is the orthogonal projection of $g$ on $V$,then $(g-Pg)(x);x\in [0,1]$

The problem is I can't get the meaning of orthogonal projection of an element of a vector space and as a result I can't proceed.
I surfed the internet but could not proceed .

Please provide some guidance on how to solve the problem

Comment: With three identical questions posted by different users within about 5 minutes, I doubt that either of you has put any *own* effort into the problem ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for the orthogonal projector onto a 1D subspace is the same regardless of dimension. If $a$ is a nonzero vector in the subspace and $b$ is some other vector then

$$Pb=\frac{\langle a,b \rangle}{\| a \|^2} a.$$

In your case, if you take $a=x$ and $b=x^2$, then you get the orthogonal projector onto $V^\perp$. The orthogonal projector onto $V$ is then $I-P$.

As it happens, the formula for the orthogonal projector onto a finite dimensional subspace is *also* the same regardless of dimension, but that is not necessary for this problem.